# What is the equivalent of matrix.setScale(-1, 1) under delphi?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

In android, we can do `matrix.setScale(-1, 1);` to **FLIP_HORIZONTAL** an image. I try to do the same under delphi like :

```
aMatrix := Canvas.Matrix * TMatrix.CreateScaling(-1, 1);
Canvas.SetMatrix(aMatrix);
```

but it's not work :( What did i miss ? How can i FLIP_HORIZONTAL an image in delphi (inside the canvas, so playing with the matrix)

Comment: I don't know for sure, but do know that matrix multiplication is not commutative, i.e.a * b is not the same as b * a.

Comment: no, didn't know ... but i thnink yes you are right, but not sure

Answer (score 0):

I found :

```
aMatrixRotationCenter.X := (width / 2) + Canvas.Matrix.m31;
aMatrixRotationCenter.Y := (height / 2) + Canvas.Matrix.m32;
aMatrix := Canvas.Matrix * TMatrix.CreateTranslation(-aMatrixRotationCenter.X,-aMatrixRotationCenter.Y);
aMatrix := aMatrix * TMatrix.CreateScaling(-1, 1); // matrix.setScale(-1, 1);
aMatrix := aMatrix * TMatrix.CreateTranslation(aMatrixRotationCenter.X,aMatrixRotationCenter.Y);
Canvas.SetMatrix(aMatrix);
```